# React Higher order components, that modifies the input element of wrapped component in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-hooks

I have a higher order component like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const NewComponent = ( WrappedComponent ) => {
    class UpdatedComponent extends React.Component {
        render() {
           // Custom Hook
           // const values = useCustomHook(InitialState);
            return(
                <WrappedComponent />
            )
        }
    }
    return UpdatedComponent;
};

export { NewComponent };
```

And the wrapped component like these.

```
const App = () => {

    return(
        <Form>

            <input
                type = 'text'
                placeholder = 'Enter your name' />

            <input
                type = 'email'
                placeholder = 'Enter your email' />

            <button
                type = 'submit'>
                    Submit
            </button>

        </Form>
    )
}
```

The thing is i want to iterate through input elements in the wrapped components and construct a compound state, which i will pass a an Argument to the custom hook in the hoc? Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Please show more examples, you telling us about Form with input elements - can you show a usage example, and what is the desired outcome i.e how the from should look like after the HOC

Comment: You don't really need a higher-order component for this and you should already have a state based on the form in `WrappedComponent` because input elements should be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in React. It would help if you clarify what is your end goal, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DennisVash I have edited the description. Please check it

Comment: Ok still, how Form should look like after the HOC

Comment: The form will be the same, i will pass the values returned from the custom hook in HOC to wrapped component as props.

Comment: React hooks only work with functional components, not class-based components. HOCs can still be created using functional components, so I'm rather just pointing out potential issue. It also isn't clear how this HOC is used, how it augments a wrapped component, and how the two code snippets relate to one another. This question needs more/clearer details.

Comment: What does "compound state" means? You mean controlled state? Are you asking how to iterate `WrappedComponent` children and if its an `input` how to pass `state` to it? If so its impossible.

Comment: Okay,  I will use return an Functional Component in HOC, then how can i parse through each field in Wrapped component and construct component state using name attribute of that field

Comment: You can check if there is `WrappedComponent.children` prop... But I dont think you can do anything useful with it

Comment: Okay! I want to have a form component, which contains input fields. Based on the input fields i want to create a compound state using name attribute  of each field  and pass that state to the custom hook, then the values returned form the hook, are to be passed to the form component. Any idea how to do this @DennisVash

Comment: I dont think you can do it with a HOC, maybe your question is unclear to me, hope someone will add an answer

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to create a custom hook to manage form state in your react component?

Comment: @itzzmeakhi Why do you want to create data from jsx, in React you usually create jsx from data. You want to parse jsx and create data that you pass to a hook but you should pass data that you can pass to the hook and create the jsx from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not parse jsx and create data from that but you have not really demonstrated why you need to do this and maybe have a valid use case for it.

Here is how you could parse jsx (the html created from it):

```js
const useCustomHook = (state) => {
  if (state !== null) {
    console.log('custom hook, state is:', state);
  }
};

const Form = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);
  const ref = React.useRef();
  useCustomHook(state);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    setState(
      Array.from(ref.current.querySelectorAll('input')).map(
        ({ type, placeholder }) => ({
          type,
          placeholder,
        })
      )
    );
  }, []);
  return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```